# concatenate row values for the same index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My initial DataFrame looks as follows:

```
   A    B  quantity
0  1  foo         1
1  1  baz         2
2  1  bar         2
3  1  faz         1
4  2  foo         2
5  2  bar         1
6  3  foo         3
```

I need to group it by 'A' and make a list of 'B' multiplied by 'quantity':

```
   A                               B
0  1  [foo, baz, baz, bar, bar, faz]
1  2                 [foo, foo, bar]
2  3                 [foo, foo, foo]
```

Currently I'm using groupby() and then apply():

```py
def itemsToList(tdf, column):

    collist = []
    for row in tdf[column].iteritems():
        collist = collist + tdf['quantity'][row[0]]*[row[1]]

    return pd.Series({column: collist})

gb = df.groupby('A').apply(itemsToList, 'B')
```

I doubt it is an efficient way, so I'm looking for a good, "pandaic" method to achieve this.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings). I think it's similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done in 2 steps, generate a new column that creates the expanded str values, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'A' and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) `list` to this new column:

```
In [62]:
df['expand'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([x['B']] * x['quantity']), axis=1)
df.groupby('A')['expand'].apply(list)

Out[62]:
A
1    [foo, baz,baz, bar,bar, faz]
2                  [foo,foo, bar]
3                   [foo,foo,foo]
Name: expand, dtype: object
```

**EDIT**

OK after taking *inspiration* from @Jianxun Li's answer:

```
In [130]:
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: np.repeat(x['B'].values, x['quantity']).tolist())

Out[130]:
A
1    [foo, baz, baz, bar, bar, faz]
2                   [foo, foo, bar]
3                   [foo, foo, foo]
dtype: object
```

Also this works:

```
In [131]:
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: list(np.repeat(x['B'].values, x['quantity'])))

Out[131]:
A
1    [foo, baz, baz, bar, bar, faz]
2                   [foo, foo, bar]
3                   [foo, foo, foo]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This works, but leaves `df` different to how we found it, which I'd say is not ideal.

Comment: @LondonRob sorry what do you mean, do you mean the fact I added an intermediate column? The intermediate step is necessary as I can't figure out how to get the `apply` and `lambda` to not try to expand the list and remain 1-dimensional

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (and exactly what I'm just struggling with now! There *must* be a clever way!)

Comment: @LondonRob the problem here is that I get messed up results with the seemingly sensible ways: `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: list(x['B'] * x['quantity'])) ` or `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['B'] * x['quantity']) )`

Comment: @LondonRob if I try `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: ','.join([x['B']] * x['quantity']))` I get `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional` so I'm racking my brain on this one

Comment: Yes, that's *exactly* what I'm doing too. Can't we use [Jeff's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17841294/2071807) of returning a Series? I can get pretty close using that....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82483/discussion-between-londonrob-and-edchum).

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it. First reshape the `df` using `pivot_table` and then `apply` `np.repeat().tolist()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df

Out[52]: 
   A    B  quantity
0  1  foo         1
1  1  baz         2
2  1  bar         2
3  1  faz         1
4  2  foo         2
5  2  bar         1
6  3  foo         3

df.pivot('A','B','quantity').fillna(0).apply(lambda row: np.repeat(row.index.values, row.values.astype(int)).tolist(), axis=1)

Out[53]: 
A
1    [bar, bar, baz, baz, faz, foo]
2                   [bar, foo, foo]
3                   [foo, foo, foo]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I used `np.repeat` to solve my `groupby` approach ;-)

Comment: @EdChum Agree with your answer. `pivot_table` reshaping is unnecessary. `groupby` is a much cleaner way to do it. :-)