# How to use groupby to concatenate strings in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I currently have dataframe at the top. Is there a way to use a groupby function to get another dataframe to group the data and concatenate the words into the format like further below using python pandas?

Thanks

[[image: enter image description [1]]

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can apply `join` on your column after `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('index')['words'].apply(','.join)
```

Example:

```
In [326]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b','c','c'], 'words':['asd','rtr','s','rrtttt','dsfd']})
df

Out[326]:
  id   words
0  a     asd
1  a     rtr
2  b       s
3  c  rrtttt
4  c    dsfd

In [327]:
df.groupby('id')['words'].apply(','.join)

Out[327]:
id
a        asd,rtr
b              s
c    rrtttt,dsfd
Name: words, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want to save even more ink, you don't need to use `.apply()` since `.agg()` can take a function to apply to each group:

`df.groupby('id')['words'].agg(','.join)`

OR

```
# this way you can add multiple columns and different aggregates as needed.
df.groupby('id').agg({'words': ','.join})
```