# How to add string numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following Datarame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    'col_3': [14, 15, 16, 19]
})
```

I try to convert the numeric to string, and then combine each row into one string

I can achieve this by using :

```
df.apply(lambda x : ''.join(x.astype(str)),1) 

Out[209]: 
0    0414
1    1515
2    2616
3    3719
dtype: object# notice here dtype is object
```

---

***This is the question***

Then , I try to using `sum`

```
df.astype(str).sum(1)
Out[211]: 
0     414.0
1    1515.0
2    2616.0
3    3719.0
dtype: float64
```

Notice here the `dtype` become `float` not `object`.

---

Here is more information :

```
df.astype(str).applymap(type)
Out[221]: 
           col_1          col_2          col_3
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
3  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

***Why `sum` have this wired behavior? Is there any way to block it convert `str` back to `float` ?***

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Check [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38470550/2901002).

Comment: @jezrael thank you !!! that wired `try` `except` made this ....

Comment: Yes, is not problem if signed your question as dupe?

Comment: @jezrael go ahead dude ! :-) plz mark it as dup ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum didn't work because while returning the series since there are only numbers it converted to respective float dtype format. It will be `object` only if it is `mixed datatype` when applying standard functions.

For example when you do

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_1': [0, 1, 2, 3],
    'col_2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
    'col_3': [14, 15, 16, 'b']
})

df.astype(str).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
  
0    0414
1    1515
2    2616
3     37b
dtype: object
```

One alternative for doing sum is with cumsum so dtype will be preserved i.e

```
s = df.astype(str).cumsum(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

Output:

```
0    0414
1    1515
2    2616
3    3719
Name: col_3, dtype: object
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It help me to know a new way for this `cumsum` great ,  but why pandas dataframe have this wired behavior ...

Comment: As I said after aggregation series will be returned. When the series is completely numbers it converts the dtype to float. May be a bug need to go through docs for more info

Comment: Kindly try `df.col_1.astype(str).sum()`

Comment: Here `series is not returned` but a string so no typecasting. Maybe whenever function returns series it tries to typecast if no errors on typecasting then typecasted series will be returned else the original series. Hope it clarifies your doubt

Comment: I reading through the pandas' help file ...and I can not find a word mention about this procedure , Have any idea how to block this wired process ?

Comment: To be honest Im searching for preserving the dtype the whole time. Will surely update the solution once Im successful in finding that

Comment: I just want to find a block to stop this wired behavior that `try` make the mission impossible

Comment: For speed we can cheat it by adding some string to end of the dframe and select everything except the last one. But it is bit of hard word.

Comment: I just do not understand why they add the try except at the end ...

Comment: Maybe because pandas usually takes data from external text source in real life and since the case of adding numbers as string is less so they might have added `try` and `except`.. Its better we post a feature request.

Comment: Sure , will discuss in the link answer with PiR and accept answer holder there.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some, you can try this way:

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.sum(),1)
```

Output:

```
0    0414
1    1515
2    2616
3    3719
dtype: object
```

Comment: Great this work also, But Just do not know why my approach did not work ...confused me a lot ...

Comment: Yeah, there is some casting done in the DataFrame method which appears to be different in the Series method.

Comment: Basically, by only using `sum`, it do paste the str `number` together and then convert it back to numeric ..., I try to find a way block this automatic process but failed ...

Comment: Even df.col_1.astype(str).sum() works as you expected.

Comment: It must be something passed when doing the pd.DataFrame.sum method versus doing a pd.Series.sum.

Comment: Yes , I try it , it work as what we expected.PS: By reading through the pandas's file , I can not find where it mentioned `DataFrame` `sum`  have this behavior ...

Comment: @Wen maybe my answer helps

Comment: @Bharathshetty case solved , kindly check the duplicated question .. seems there is no way for us to block it . I hate that `try`....

Comment: As i said it will convert it to number if there are only numeric type. Hope my answer says it in brief. The other answer is so in depth