# pandas method .isin() automatically converts datatypes in element comparisons?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Wondering if someone can help me here. When I take a regular python list containing strings, and check to see if a pandas series (pla.id) has a value that matches a value in that list. It works.

Which is great and all but I wonder how it's able to compare strings to ints... is there documentation somewhere that states that it will convert under the hood before comparing those values??

I wasn't able to find anything on the .isin() page of pandas documentation..

[image]

Also super interesting is that when I try pandas indexing it fails due to a type comparison. 
[image]

So my two questions:

1. Does pandas.series.isin(some_list_of_strings) method automatically convert the values in the series (which are int values) to strings before doing a value comparison?
2. If so, why doesn't pandas indexing i.e. (df[df.series == 'some value']) not do the same thing? What is the thinking behind this? If I wanted to accomplish the same thing I would have to do df[df.series.astype(str) == ''] or df[df.series.astype(str).isin(some_list_of_strings)] to access those values in the df that match

**After some digging I think this might be due to the pandas object datatype? but I have no understanding of why this works. Also this doesn't explain why the below works... since it is a int dtype**
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but maybe `(pla.id).isin(skus)` can help?

Comment: Also , when there is str and the sublist is numeric , the `isin` function failed

Comment: Dror -- That also does what I wouldn't expect.

Comment: So the question is to confirm if pandas will in fact convert the series when checking the list in the .isin() method (skus is a list of strings)

Comment: I edited it to make it easier to understand.. I hope

Comment: Wen could you elaborate please?

Comment: `pla.id.astype(str).isin([100089])` will failed return all False..

Comment: Yes that is true. So weird that it converts one way. I suspect this has to do with how numpy datatypes store values (since dtype object comes from numpy) but I'm having trouble understanding why

Comment: May can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470550/why-is-a-sum-of-strings-converted-to-floats