# Why does transposing a DataFrame with strings and timedeltas convert the dtype?

Tags: python, pandas

This behavior seems odd to me: the `id` column (a string) gets converted to a timestamp upon transposing the `df` if the other column is a timedelta.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['00115', '01222', '32333'],
                   'val': [12, 14, 170]})
df['val'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.val, unit='Minutes')

print(df.T)
#                         0                      1                      2
#id  0 days 00:00:00.000000 0 days 00:00:00.000001 0 days 00:00:00.000032
#val      365 days 05:49:12      426 days 02:47:24     5174 days 06:27:00

type(df.T[0][0])
#pandas._libs.tslib.Timedelta
```

Without the timedelta it works as I'd expect, and the `id` column remains a string, even though the other column is an integer and all of the strings could be safely cast to integers.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['00115', '01222', '32333'],
                    'val': [1, 1231, 1413]})

type(df2.T[0][0])
#str
```

Why does the type of `id` get changed in the first instance, but not the second?

Comment: It looks like a bug. I answered a question similar to this one a while ago, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470550/why-is-a-sum-of-strings-converted-to-floats/38470963#38470963. Fundamentally, the way that Pandas deals with datatypes is a bit messy.

Comment: This seems to happen because `df.id` is of dtype `object`. Then, because `df.T` will have mixed types. pandas'll try to infer which type the columns will have, and ends up choosing `timedelta` in this case. If you had dtype `int`, `bytes` or any other specified object, this wouldnt happen.. Now, why the `dtype` is `object` and not `str` has already been asked/answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object/21020411 , and is quite confusing to me honestly

Comment: I just thought it was odd it tried to choose in the timedelta case and not the int case. If one of the `id`s cant be converted to timedelta they all remain strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dataframe should be thought of in columns.  Each column must have a single data type.  When you transpose, you are changing which cells are now associated with each other in the new columns.  Prior to transpose, you had an string column and a timedelta column.  After transpose, each column had a string and a timedelta.  Pandas has to decide how to cast the new columns.  It decided to go with timedelta.  It is my opinion that this is a goofy choice.

You can change this behavior by changing the dtype on a newly constructed dataframe.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, df.columns, df.index, dtype=object)

                     0                  1                   2
id               00115              01222               32333
val  365 days 05:49:12  426 days 02:47:24  5174 days 06:27:00
```

Comment: Nice answer. `It is my opinion that this is a goofy choice`: Has anyone documented how Pandas decides `dtype` for a series given different constituent types, e.g. what priority logic (if  any)? It's probably hidden away in obfuscated code, but this issue comes up quite often.

Comment: I can show an example of it choosing `object` which I think is appropriate.  But other times it casts ints to floats which I also think is appropriate.  To answer your question, idk.  I certainly haven't.

Comment: It is very messy. If you have `df['id'] = df.is.astype(bytes)` first, then it'd just cast to `object`. Seems so arbitrary

Comment: Technically, it isn't arbitrary.  It's written somewhere.  It may be as simple as timedelta having a safe casting priority over string /shrug

Answer (score -3):

The point of using the method to_timedelta is to *Convert argument to timedelta*, per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html. This will update the type.

The second time you never ran the to_timedelta method and the values are kept in their original state, as object (strings) for the table.

Comment: I don't think this answers why Pandas chooses to trigger conversion of '00115' to `timedelta` on transposing.