# I need to create a python list object, or any object, out of a pandas DataFrame object grouping pieces of values from different rows

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame has a string in the first column, and a number in the second one:

```
            GEOSTRING  IDactivity
9     wydm2p01uk0fd2z           2
10    wydm86pg6r3jyrg           2
11    wydm2p01uk0fd2z           2
12    wydm80xfxm9j22v           2
39    wydm9w92j538xze           4
40    wydm8km72gbyuvf           4
41    wydm86pg6r3jyrg           4
42    wydm8mzt874p1v5           4
43    wydm8mzmpz5gkt8           5
44    wydm86pg6r3jyrg           5
45    wydm8w1q8bjfpcj           5
46    wydm8w1q8bjfpcj           5
```

What I want to do is to manipulate this DataFrame in order to have a list object that contains a string, made out of the 5th character for each "GEOSTRING" value, for each different "IDactivity" value. 
So in this case, I have 3 different "IDactivity" values, and I will have in my list object 3 strings that look like this:

```
['2828', '9888','8888']
```

where again, the symbols you see in each string, are the 5th value of each "GEOSTRING" value.

What I'm asking is a solution, or an approach, that doesn't involve a too complicated `for` loop and have it as efficient as possible since I have to manipulate lots of data. I'd like it to be clean and fast.

I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this can be done easily as follows as a one liner: (considered to be pretty fast too)

```
result = df.groupby('IDactivity')['GEOSTRING'].apply(lambda x:''.join(x.str[4])).tolist()
```

this groups the dataframe by values of `IDactivity` then select from each corresponding string of `GEOSTRING` column the 5th element (index 4) and joins it with the other corresponding strings. Finally we add `tolist()` method to get the output as list not pandas Series.

output:

```
['2828', '9888', '8888']
```

Documentation:

[pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
[pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution involving a temp column, and taking inspiration for the key operation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings):

```
# create a temp column with the character we want from each string
dframe['Temp'] = dframe['GEOSTRING'].apply(lambda x: x[4])

# groupby ID and then concatenate using a sneaky call to .sum()
dframe.groupby('IDactivity')['Temp'].sum().tolist()
```

Result:

```
['2828', '9888', '8888']
```

Comment: This is actually useful since I'm learning how to handle dataframes. Rayhane answer is probably faster, but you have been helpful too, thanks