# Pandas: sum values in column if multiple values match str/contains/join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am having trouble searching one list of numbers from one dataframe in the column of another. I am dealing with a case where different numbers refer to the same item. 
I am having trouble searching one list of numbers from one dataframe in the column of another. I am dealing with a case where different numbers refer to the same item.

In my sample code, "term2" has entries with both code 'AAAA' and 'CCCC'.

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'term' : ['term1','term2','term3','term4','term1','term3','term2'],
        'code': ['ZZZZ', 'AAAA','XXXX','QQQQ','ZZZZ','XXXX','CCCC'],
        'count':['1','3','1','1','1','1','3']
        }
        )
df1 = df1[['term'] + df1.columns[:-1].tolist()]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'name': ['Dan','Sara','Conroy','Steve'],
        'rate': ['3','3.5','5.2','3'],
        'location': ['FL','OH','NM','NM'],
        'code': ['XXXX','BBBB','PPPP','TTTT'],
        'allcodes': ['XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ','AAAA,BBBB,CCCC','PPPP,QQQQ,RRRR','SSSS,TTTT,UUUU']
         }
         )

df2 = df2[['name','rate','location','code','allcodes']]
pmissnlist = df1['code'].values.tolist()
df3 = df2[df2['allcodes'].str.contains('|'.join(pmissnlist))].reset_index()

df4 = pd.DataFrame(df3['allcodes'].str.split(',').tolist(),
                            index=df3.code).stack(level=0).reset_index(level=0)
matches = df4[df4[0].isin(df1.code)]
df5 = df3[df3.code.isin(matches.code)]
df5 = df5.drop_duplicates()#drops duplicate rows

df5_temp = df5.set_index(['name','rate','location','code']).allcodes.str.split(',',expand = True)\
                                  .stack().reset_index(4,drop = True).reset_index(name = 'allcodes')
df5 = pd.merge(df1, df5_temp, left_on = 'code', right_on = 'allcodes')
df5 = df5.drop('allcodes', 1).groupby(['code_y','term','count','name','rate','location']).code_x.\
                                    apply(','.join).reset_index().sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)
print(df5)
```

The output is:

```
      code_y   term   count  name   rate  location  code_x
0     BBBB     term2  3      Sara   3.5   OH        AAAA,CCCC
1     PPPP     term4  1      Conroy 5.2   NM        QQQQ
2     XXXX     term1  1      Dan    3     FL        ZZZZ,ZZZZ
3     XXXX     term3  1      Dan    3     FL        XXXX,XXXX
```

There are two instances of term2 associated with Sara, so I want her count to be 6, not 3. The counts should be 2 for each of Dan's rows, too. If I understand the dataframe correctly, this is expected: the dataframe contains the data that satisfies the condition of the first term2. When the second instance is compared, the related data already exists in the dataframe.

How do I sum the count values where multiple codes are matched in the "allcode" field of df2?

EDIT: Adding desired outcome

```
      code_y   term   count  name   rate  location  code_x
0     BBBB     term2  6      Sara   3.5   OH        AAAA,CCCC
1     PPPP     term4  1      Conroy 5.2   NM        QQQQ
2     XXXX     term1  2      Dan    3     FL        ZZZZ,ZZZZ
3     XXXX     term3  2      Dan    3     FL        XXXX,XXXX
```

EDIT2:
The problem is with the groupby.

Here is the output of df5 BEFORE the statement with the groupby:

```
    term code_x  count    name rate location code_y allcodes
0  term1   ZZZZ      1     Dan    3       FL   XXXX     ZZZZ
1  term1   ZZZZ      1     Dan    3       FL   XXXX     ZZZZ
2  term2   AAAA      3    Sara  3.5       OH   BBBB     AAAA
3  term3   XXXX      1     Dan    3       FL   XXXX     XXXX
4  term3   XXXX      1     Dan    3       FL   XXXX     XXXX
5  term4   QQQQ      1  Conroy  5.2       NM   PPPP     QQQQ
6  term2   CCCC      2    Sara  3.5       OH   BBBB     CCCC
7  term6   TTTT      1   Steve    3       NM   TTTT     TTTT
```

So, essentially I want counts for the column with the same term (term2 for Sara, and term3 & term4 for Dan) before the groupby.

Comment: can you add a manually-created table which represents the desired outcome, e.g. copy the table below "The output is:" in your post and fill in with the desired outcome?

Comment: I have added the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small function to get the expected output.

```
def f(x):
     return pd.Series(dict(count = x['count'].sum(), 
                        code_x = "%s" % ', '.join(x['code_x'])))

df5=df5.groupby(['code_y','term','name','rate','location'])[['code_x','count']].apply(f).reset_index()
```

output

```
  code_y   term    name rate location      code_x  count
0   BBBB  term2    Sara  3.5       OH  AAAA, CCCC      6
1   PPPP  term4  Conroy  5.2       NM        QQQQ      1
2   XXXX  term1     Dan    3       FL  ZZZZ, ZZZZ      2
3   XXXX  term3     Dan    3       FL  XXXX, XXXX      2
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841294/6626530

Comment: This did it. I realized the problem that I was having was with my groupby statement (see EDIT2 in my original post). This allows the values to be summed. Thanks!

Comment: So you got the expected output ?

Comment: in my example, yes. in my actual data, no but I think that I have an idea. The one row which should have been summed to 6 came out 9, but I think something went wrong further up in the script that added duplicate rows (I'm  using drop_duplicates, so I don't know how that happened.)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC , By using `str.split` and `len`

```
df['count']*=df['code_x'].str.split(',').apply(len)
df
Out[1105]: 
  code_y   term  count    name  rate location     code_x
0   BBBB  term2      6    Sara   3.5       OH  AAAA,CCCC
1   PPPP  term4      1  Conroy   5.2       NM       QQQQ
2   XXXX  term1      2     Dan   3.0       FL  ZZZZ,ZZZZ
3   XXXX  term3      2     Dan   3.0       FL  XXXX,XXXX
```

EDIT :

```
    df.groupby(['code_y','term'],as_index=False).agg({'count':'sum','name':'first','rate':'first','location':'first','code_x':lambda x : ','.join(x),'allcodes':'first'})
Out[1130]: 
  code_y   term  count    name  rate location     code_x allcodes
0   BBBB  term2      5    Sara   3.5       OH  AAAA,CCCC     AAAA
1   PPPP  term4      1  Conroy   5.2       NM       QQQQ     QQQQ
2   TTTT  term6      1   Steve   3.0       NM       TTTT     TTTT
3   XXXX  term1      2     Dan   3.0       FL  ZZZZ,ZZZZ     ZZZZ
4   XXXX  term3      2     Dan   3.0       FL  XXXX,XXXX     XXXX
```

Comment: I think this might cause issue. Let's say 5 on the first record and 6 on the second one , then If I understood correctly, expected answer is 11. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @ Wen you  did it  :) -

Comment: @Shijo it is start from the df5 :-)