# How to merge rows in a pandas dataframe that share the same designated index entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, with string entries, eg:

```
Col1 Col2
E1     K1
E2     K2
E3     K3
...
```

I want to create an index on Col2 but the entries there are not unique. So I would like to merge all rows of shared entries in Col2. Say K2, K3 are identical. Then after the merge what I would like to have is the Col1 values serialized into a list forming just one row, ie:

```
Col1 Col2
E1     K1
[E2, E3]     K2
...
```

What would be the cleanest way of achieving this?

Comment: how do you determine that K2 and K3 are identical?

Comment: @Onyambu k2 == k3; the entries are all strings; sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: then you should just use k2 in both cases. no need of k3. replace k3 ith k2

Comment: _why_ do you want to do this? is this for reporting/human viewability? if so, that's ok, but if it's for data analysis, it's almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: @acushner what approach would you suggest instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby: How to get a union of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings)

Answer (score 1):

First change `K3` into `K2` then groupby column2 and aggregate on it

```
 df[df=='K3']='K2'
 df.groupby('Col2').agg(list)
          Col1
Col2          
K1        [E1]
K2    [E2, E3]
```

Comment: See my comment under Wen’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `mapper` with `groupby`

```
df.set_index('Col2').groupby(by={'K1':'K1','K2':'K2','K3':'K2'},axis=0).Col1.apply(list)
Out[116]: 
K1        [E1]
K2    [E2, E3]
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perhaps my original post was misleading, but the table above was just an example. A priori I no way of knowing which indices occur repeatedly, and in particular the dataframe has a variable number if rows.

Answer (score 0):

since you don't know a priori what the dupes are, you can do:

```
df.groupby('Col2').agg(lambda s: list(s))
```

for some reason `.agg(list)` doesn't work for me...