# Python: how to merge 2 columns without overwriting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to merge 2 columns in python: 
both column A and column B contains names of states. I'd love to merge column An and column B to get the "Ideal Result" column. How can i achieve it in python? Thanks a lot!
And this is in Python; they are dataframes.

[image]

Comment: What kind of column are we talking about? A spreadsheet column? A dataframe column? A column in a nested list?

Comment: something with `row[0] or row[1]` maybe? we need to see your input & some code if possible

Comment: sorry i wasn't being clear. they are dataframe columns in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby: How to get a union of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings)

Comment: If they are object types you can just concat them `df.A+df.B`

Comment: Assuming you want to use Python to modify an Excel file. Take a look at https://www.xlwings.org/ this is a simple but powerful python library to modify Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a dataframe, I think you could try to use `np.where`:

```
df['idealcol'] = np.where(df['A'].isnull(), df['B'] , df['A'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Like your code very much! clean and quick!

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is in some excel in a dataframe df:

```
df['Ideal Result'] = df.A.str.cat(df.B)
```

If not:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("\\your_csv.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It answered my question!

Comment: If this solves your problem, do upvote  for future users

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is check if string in column A is null or empty

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['AL',''],'B':['','BL']})
df['ideal_col']=np.where((df['A']=='') |( df['A'].isnull()), np.where(df['B'].isnull(),'',df['B']) , df['A'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It answered my question!