# Pandas GroupBy String is joining column names not column values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group a DataFrame which consists of a DocID and a string using this [SO as guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings) but instead of a dataframe with 1 row per DocID and all the string values separated by a space, I end up with a column containing the column values.

**Can someone point out my error?**

**Sample Data**

```
StringDF.head()

    DocID                                   LessStopWords
0   dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    judgment of the court chamber 
1   dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    the request proceedings
2   dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    legal context law
3   dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    article 1 directive
4   dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    the status taken
```

**My Code**

```
DocsForTopicModel=StringDF.groupby(['DocID'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
```

**My Output**

```
     DocID                                  LessStopWords
 0  010b158d-8c0b-49ad-9340-774893e4f62f    DocID LessStopWords
 1  02874037-416d-4b91-8e2d-1a288b8c3a7b    DocID LessStopWords
 2  05b9ea7b-b5f0-4757-854c-b303a295f606    DocID LessStopWords
 3  06f87756-4dbe-4199-a8e2-b504451e823a    DocID LessStopWords
 4  070bd4d1-6830-447e-9042-12c6def18822    DocID LessStopWords
```

**My Hoped For Output**

```
     DocID                                      LessStopWords
     0  010b158d-8c0b-49ad-9340-774893e4f62f    judgment of the court chamber the request proceedings legal context law article 1 directive
     1  02874037-416d-4b91-8e2d-1a288b8c3a7b    ...
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine, so would df.groupby(['DocID'],as_index=False).LessStopWords.apply(' '.join)

Comment: I get a type error TypeError: sequence item 159: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @Vaishali Yep, but with a blankspace, Something like this: `df.groupby('DocID')['LessStopWords'].apply(' '.join).to_frame('LessStopWords').reset_index()`

Comment: @AntonvBR, yes the code is with space, may be not very visible in the comment

Comment: @Vaishali You can enclose your code with **back-tick (` `)**

Comment: @mobcdi, may be you have a NaN or some other float value at 159. You can try `df.groupby(['DocID'],as_index=False).LessStopWords.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `.str.cat(sep=' ')` (to do concatenation):

```
>>> df.groupby('DocID')['LessStopWords'].apply(lambda ser: ser.str.cat(sep=' '))
DocID
dd9ae7c8-7e98-4539-ab81-24c4780a6756    judgment of the court chamber the request proc...
Name: LessStopWords, dtype: object
```

More examples in [Working with Text Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#concatenation).

---

Larger example:

```
>>> import string
>>> import uuid
>>> 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> uids = np.random.choice([uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(3)], size=10)
>>> words = np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), size=10)
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'DocID': uids, 'LessStopWords': words})
>>> df
                                  DocID LessStopWords
0  8ec3faf7-a771-4e50-87d7-127a69d4d738             p
1  0befc0aa-9311-4154-bced-00a280c99cdd             q
2  8ec3faf7-a771-4e50-87d7-127a69d4d738             t
3  de1021d3-ce47-4f56-8e4d-47d389473dd6             j
4  0befc0aa-9311-4154-bced-00a280c99cdd             L
5  8ec3faf7-a771-4e50-87d7-127a69d4d738             t
6  de1021d3-ce47-4f56-8e4d-47d389473dd6             g
7  0befc0aa-9311-4154-bced-00a280c99cdd             D
8  0befc0aa-9311-4154-bced-00a280c99cdd             d
9  8ec3faf7-a771-4e50-87d7-127a69d4d738             J
>>> df.groupby('DocID')['LessStopWords'].apply(lambda ser: ser.str.cat(sep=' '))
DocID
0befc0aa-9311-4154-bced-00a280c99cdd    q L D d
8ec3faf7-a771-4e50-87d7-127a69d4d738    p t t J
de1021d3-ce47-4f56-8e4d-47d389473dd6        j g
Name: LessStopWords, dtype: object
```