# How to concatenate rows while preserving all rows and have one result value per group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to generate a unique group-value for each observation made up of the contents of a column concatenated together, while keeping all the rows intact.

I have observations that can be grouped on a specific column (column `A` below). I want to create a unique value per group made of the content of each row of this group, but keeping the rows untouched.

I have tried solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298178/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings), but these solutions collapse the results, leaving one row per group, whereas I wish to keep all rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
     'B': [345, 366, 299, 455, 879, 321, 957, 543]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

   A    B
0  1  345
1  2  366
2  3  299
3  3  455
4  4  879
5  5  321
6  5  957
7  5  689
8  6  543

df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str)
df['B_concat'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply('/'.join)

print(df)

   A    B     B_concat
0  1  345          NaN
1  2  366          345
2  3  299          366
3  3  455      299/455
4  4  879          879
5  5  321  321/957/689
6  5  957          543
7  5  689          NaN
8  6  543          NaN
```

Units in the same group should have the same `B_concat` value.

```
   A    B     B_concat
0  1  345          345
1  2  366          366
2  3  299      299/455
3  3  455      299/455
4  4  879          879
5  5  321  321/957/689
6  5  957  321/957/689
7  5  689  321/957/689
8  6  543          543
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible assign to new column:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(str)
df['B_concat'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform('/'.join)
```

One line solution should be:

```
df['B_concat'] = df['B'].astype(str).groupby(df['A']).transform('/'.join)
print (df)
   A    B B_concat
0  1  345      345
1  2  366      366
2  3  299  299/455
3  3  455  299/455
4  4  879      879
5  5  321  321/957
6  5  957  321/957
7  6  543      543
```

Or:

```
df['B_concat'] = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x: '/'.join(x.astype(str)))
```