# groupby and extract data

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

new in pandas and I was able to create a dataframe from a csv file. I was also able to sort it out.

What I am struggling now is the following: I give an image as an example from a pandas data frame.
[image: A data frame]

First column is the index,
Second column is a group number
Third column is what happened.

I want based on the second column to take out the third column on the same unique data frame.

I highlight few examples: For the number 9 return back the sequence
[60,61,70,51]

For the number 6 get back the sequence
[65,55,56]

For the number 8 get back the single element 8.

How groupby can be used to do this extraction?

Thanks a lot
Regards
Alex

Comment: Please provide actual data we can easily copy&paste instead of an image. Then it becomes easier to help.

Comment: As already said [don't post pictures of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Plus do you only want to get those exact groups? So `9,6, and 8` or all groups?

Comment: And it would help to have the columns names...

Comment: thanks. I want to extract the values. My wording about unique was on storing all those vectors on the same data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings) we can extract following code to receive the desired result.

```
dataframe =  pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4], 'groupNumber':[9,9,9,9,9], 'value':[12,13,14,15,16]})
grouped = dataframe.groupby('groupNumber')['value'].apply(list)
```

Comment: yes my question was answered there. My solutions is to apply a list after the group by df_sorted_unique.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list).