# Pandas dataframe join/consolidate into single column as string concatenation, do it cheap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe imported from csv with format as follows:

`IP            OS         port        protocol    ...
 0.0.0.0       Linux      5000        tcp         ...
 0.0.0.0       Linux      5001        tcp         ...
 0.0.0.0       Linux      5002        udp         ...
 0.0.0.1       Windows    4008        tcp         ...
 0.0.0.1       Windows    4009        udp         ...
 ...           ...        ...         ...         ...`

I need to consolidate this dataframe in order for `IP` to be unique, like so:

`IP            OS         port                               ...
 0.0.0.0       Linux      5000(tcp), 5001(tcp), 5002(udp)    ...
 0.0.0.1       Windows    4008(tcp), 4009(udp)               ...
 ...           ...        ...                                ...`

In the resulting dataframe, only those three columns matter, I do not care about the rest. Note the string concatenation in `port`. Also, inplace processing is an option but no requirement as I will further process the data. The original table is quite long though.

Everything I found only merges into several columns, not into a single one. As I want the operation to be cheap and fast (long table) I am wondering if there is an onboard method that I am missing.
My ideas form reading the docu, all not quite up to the task as I am not that familiar with pandas:

- `dataframe.join()`: joins into separate columns next to each other, but I need the single one.
- `dataframe.merge()`: does not make the key unique.
- Loop over the field and do the string concatenation like `if element is in dataframe [...]` to kind of copy the ports up to the first occurrence of `IP`, then do a `dataframe.drop_duplicates(['IP'], keep=first, inplace=true)` to delete every duplicate of the key except the now consolidated first one. This seems really expensive though.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings) will not do the job as it joins the strings to fields in a single column, but does not provide an option to concatenate braces into the string or format it in any way. I am explicitly not looking for a field as an output but for a clean string that can be formatted as seen above.

Is there a way to go that I do not know of or a best practice to do this the pythonic way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas groupby: How to get a union of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings)

Comment: @Georgy unfortunately not. Edited to separate my question from your finding. I am specifically looking for a string solution that I can format, not a field as asked in the suggested duplicate. Totally different approach, would have liked it to be that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First join columns together with `()` and then use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join`:

```
df['port'] = df['port'] .astype(str) + '(' + df['protocol'] + ')'

#if possible duplicates
#df = df.drop_duplicates(['P','OS','port'])
df = df.groupby(['IP','OS'])['port'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
print (df)
        IP       OS                             port
0  0.0.0.0    Linux  5000(tcp), 5001(tcp), 5002(udp)
1  0.0.0.1  Windows             4008(tcp), 4009(udp)
```

Alternative solution if performance is important:

```
df = df.groupby(['IP','OS'])['port'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: Solution works but, according to docu, is more expensive than single call to pivot_table().

Comment: @harmonica141 - Can you test `df = df.groupby(['P','OS'])['port'].agg(', '.join).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Works fine and is even faster, I timed it. This will be the solution, let me edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `pivot_table()`:

```
df['port'] = df.port.astype(str) + '(' + df.protocol + ')'
df = df.pivot_table(index=['IP', 'OS'], values ='port', aggfunc=', '.join)
```

Result:

```
IP      OS                                  port
0.0.0.0 Linux    5000(tcp), 5001(tcp), 5002(udp)
0.0.0.1 Windows             4008(tcp), 4009(udp)
```

Comment: This is really elegant, but only works half way. The strings are being produced just fine (per line), but the join does not take place in any way. I still end up with separate lines. Checked the docu, can't explain.