# Using print and lambda function with groupby

Tags: lambda, apply, pandas-groupby

I'm using a simple code. I try to see the result of a groupby by one column. But I have the problem that one of the results is duplicate.

```py
#DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one'] ,
                   'B': ['Ar', 'Br', 'Cr', 'Ar','Ar'] ,
                   'C': ['12/15/2011', '11/11/2001', '08/30/2015', '07/3/1999','03/03/2000' ],
                      'D':[1,7,3,4,5]})


#Create a groupby and show the results

df.groupby['A'].apply(lambda x : print(x))
```

This show the result for one duplicate. What is the reason?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry y expected

Comment: Sorry I expected , that show two dataframes one dataframe for A equal to "one" value and one dataframe for A equal to " two" value. Nevertheless this return three dataframes, for A equal to "one" the dataframe is duplicate

Comment: sorry the correct code is:

Comment: df.groupby(A').apply(lambda x : print(x))

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, looks like you're looking for either one of the following:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x.sum())
```

**OR**

```
df.groupby(A').apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x))
```

and I would recommend checking out this answer for more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841294/6908282