# how to concatenate multiple strings into one

Tags: python, pandas

i am using `apply(",".join)` to concatenate,

```
ICPMMRM Charge_Code
0000000646DE9C5 SHSD15
0000000646DE9C5 6
0000000646DE9C5 10
```

```
network_report_A=network_ctct.groupby('ICPMMRM')['Charge_Code'].apply(str).apply(",".join)
network_report_A.head()
```

```
ICPMMRM
0000000646DE9C5    0, , , , ,S,H,S,D,1,5,\n,1, , , , , , , , , ,6...
0000000650DE2E7    3, , , , ,S,H,S,D,1,5,\n,4, , , , , , , , , ,6...
0000002229DE6AA    6, , , , ,S,H,S,D,1,5,\n,7, , , , , , , , ,1,7...
0000002464DED52    8, , , , , ,S,H,1,-,L,1,-,C,K,V,A,\n,9, , , , ...
0000003723CEE85    1,6, , , , ,C,C,2,-,L,2,-,C,K,V,A,\n,1,7, , , ...
Name: Charge_Code, dtype: object
```

but i expect the result like `SHSD15,6,10`

Comment: Why group by and not just take all column just like that ?

Comment: this is not standard python so tag it correctly

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: That output has more data than the input... Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings?

Comment: It seems like the problem is the `.apply(str)`, which converts the *whole group* to a string. Try removing it.

Comment: there are multiply ICPMMRM, group by is to concatenate the charge code for each ICPMMRM.

Comment: Thanks all, got it fixed after convert the Charge_Code column to str :)

Answer (score 1):

The `",".join` may be called on the values of all the column, not on each (what `apply` does). Also you don't need any `groupby` just join the values of the column

```
import pandas as pd

network_ctct = pd.DataFrame([["0000000646DE9C5", "SHSD15"],
                             ["0000000646DE9C5", "6"],
                             ["0000000646DE9C5", "10"]],
                            columns=["ICPMMRM", "Charge_Code"])

network_report_A = ",".join(network_ctct['Charge_Code'].apply(str))
print(network_report_A)  # SHSD15,6,10
```