# Groupby as list into new column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I aggreate all product names of the grouped dataframe into a new column as list or set:

```
import pandas as pd  # 2.0.3

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "customer_id": [1, 2, 3, 2, 1],
        "order_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1],
        "products": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foo", "bar"],
        "amount": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    }
)

print(df)
grouped = df.groupby(["customer_id", "order_id"])
df["product_order_count"] = grouped["amount"].transform("sum")
df["all_products"] = grouped["products"].agg(list).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Although I followed another question ([Pandas groupby: How to get a union of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings)) an exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\tt.py", line 15, in <module>
    df["all_orders"] = grouped["products"].agg(list).reset_index()
  File "c:\Users\foo\.venvs\kapa_monitor-38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3940, in __setitem__
    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)
  File "c:\Users\foo\.venvs\kapa_monitor-38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4094, in _set_item_frame_value
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column all_products
```

Expected output (`all_products`, as `list` or `set`):

```
   customer_id  order_id products  amount  product_order_count all_products
0            1         1      foo       1                    2 'foo', 'bar'
1            2         2      bar       1                    1 'bar'
2            3         3      baz       1                    1 'baz'
3            2         4      foo       1                    1 'foo'
4            1         1      bar       1                    2 'foo', 'bar'
```

Comment: Please provide the desired output for your input in a text table format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `transform` with a function that returns something that is the same length with the group:

```
df["all_products"] = grouped["products"].transform(lambda x: [list(x)]*len(x))
```

Output:

```
   customer_id  order_id products  amount  product_order_count all_products
0            1         1      foo       1                    2   [foo, bar]
1            2         2      bar       1                    1        [bar]
2            3         3      baz       1                    1        [baz]
3            2         4      foo       1                    1        [foo]
4            1         1      bar       1                    2   [foo, bar]
```

Or you can joint the strings (I don't really recommend lists in the data):

```
df["all_products"] = grouped["products"].transform(','.join)
```

which gives

```
   customer_id  order_id products  amount  product_order_count all_products
0            1         1      foo       1                    2      foo,bar
1            2         2      bar       1                    1          bar
2            3         3      baz       1                    1          baz
3            2         4      foo       1                    1          foo
4            1         1      bar       1                    2      foo,bar
```

Answer (score 2):

`grouped["products"].agg(list).reset_index()` returns a DataFrame, which is why you're seeing a `ValueError`: you're trying to set a column with a DataFrame (which contains multiple columns).

You can merge it back into the original `df`:

```
grouped = df.groupby(["customer_id", "order_id"])
df["product_order_count"] = grouped["amount"].transform("sum")
grouped = (
    grouped["products"]
    .agg(list)
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={"products": "all_products"})
)
df = pd.merge(df, grouped, on=["customer_id", "order_id"], how="left")
```

```
   customer_id  order_id products  amount  product_order_count all_products
0            1         1      foo       1                    2   [foo, bar]
1            2         2      bar       1                    1        [bar]
2            3         3      baz       1                    1        [baz]
3            2         4      foo       1                    1        [foo]
4            1         1      bar       1                    2   [foo, bar]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
# your code
grouped = df.groupby(["customer_id", "order_id"])
df["product_order_count"] = grouped["amount"].transform("sum")

# process
m = grouped['products'].agg(list).reset_index(name='all_products')
out = df.merge(m, how='left')
```

out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["product_order_count"] = df.groupby(["customer_id", "order_id"])["amount"].transform(
    "sum"
)

df["all_products"] = df.groupby(["customer_id", "order_id"])["products"].transform(
    ", ".join
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   customer_id  order_id products  amount  product_order_count all_products
0            1         1      foo       1                    2     foo, bar
1            2         2      bar       1                    1          bar
2            3         3      baz       1                    1          baz
3            2         4      foo       1                    1          foo
4            1         1      bar       1                    2     foo, bar
```